# Combining multi-input layers in neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Working on building a multi-input neural network based on tutorial [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/). When trying to combine input layers with the following code:

```
x1 = # layer 1
x2 = # layer 2
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x1.output,x2.output])
```

I get an error saying that the *layers do not have an attribute* output. Any ideas what I should try to merge these outputs to connect to the rest of my network?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved pretty quickly, but will answer for anyone else that gets stuck. Remember to put your layers into a model before concatenating or else you'll get the AttributeError. My code now looks like

```
in1 = Input()
x1 = #layer
m1 = Model(inputs = in1, outputs = x1)

# same for in2,x2,m2

combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([m1,m2])
```

From there I was able to connect it to the rest of my network without issue.